# Parse date with slashes in Pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

There is pyspark dataframe like:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([('7/1/20', )],['DATE'])
df.show()
+------+
|  DATE|
+------+
|7/1/20|
+------+
```

**Note!** data format is (m)m/(d)d/yy, like: 1/25/20, 4/5/20, 11/2/20 etc.

I tried dessisions is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63139086/string-date-column-as-d-m-y-to-date-column-in-pyspark), but it returns empty dataframe.
Example:

```py
df = df.withColumn("DATE_1",F.to_date(F.col("DATE"),"%m/%d/%y"))
df.show()
```

But it returns Nan:

```py
+------+------+
|  DATE|DATE_1|
+------+------+
|7/1/20|  null|
+------+------+
```

What can I do for parsing dates like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using `pyspark==3.2.1` and needed to set the configuration for `spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy` to `LEGACY` to use the following solution:

```
spark.conf.set('spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy', 'LEGACY')
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ('7/1/20',)
], ['Date'])

df = (
    df.withColumn('Date_1', f.to_date(f.col('Date'), 'MM/dd/yy'))
)

df.show(truncate= False)
```

output:

```
+------+----------+                                                             
|Date  |Date_1    |
+------+----------+
|7/1/20|2020-07-01|
+------+----------+
```

And if you don't want to set the configuration for `spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy` to `LEGACY`, you can use this solution:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ('7/1/20',),
    ('10/1/20',),
    ('7/10/20',),
    ('10/10/20',)
], ['Date'])

df = (
    df
    .withColumn('Date_Converted', f.regexp_replace(f.col('Date'), '^([0-9]{1}/)', '0$1'))
    .withColumn('Date_Converted', f.regexp_replace(f.col('Date_Converted'), '/([0-9]{1}/)', '/0$1'))
    .withColumn('Date_1', f.to_date(f.col('Date_Converted'), 'MM/dd/yy'))
)
```

output:

```
+--------+--------------+----------+                                            
|Date    |Date_Converted|Date_1    |
+--------+--------------+----------+
|7/1/20  |07/01/20      |2020-07-01|
|10/1/20 |10/01/20      |2020-10-01|
|7/10/20 |07/10/20      |2020-07-10|
|10/10/20|10/10/20      |2020-10-10|
+--------+--------------+----------+
```

Comment: Could you say where I can check information about it? Is any guide about cases like that one?

Comment: I knew the `MM/dd/yy` date format would work on single digit month and day values in `spark==2.4` as well, but when I tested the code I got this error: `org.apache.spark.SparkUpgradeException: You may get a different result due to the upgrading of Spark 3.0: Fail to parse '7/1/2020' in the new parser. You can set spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy to LEGACY to restore the behavior before Spark 3.0, or set to CORRECTED and treat it as an invalid datetime string.`

Comment: @Vadim.M. - [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html) might come in handy