# AWS Glue studio converting Pyspark string column to date returns null

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, etl, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I have data from an S3 bucket and want to convert the Date column from string to date. The current Date column is in the format `7/1/2022 12:0:15 AM`.

Current code I am using in AWS Glue Studio to attempt the custom transformation:

```
MyTransform (glueContext, dfc) -> DynamicFrameCollection:
      from pyspark.sql.functions import col, to_timestamp
      df = dfc.select(list(dfc.keys())[0]).toDF()
      df = df.withColumn('Date',to_timestamp(col("Date"), 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:MM:SS'))
      df_res = DynamicFrame.fromDF(df, glueContext, "df")
      return(DynamicFrameCollection({"CustomTransform0": df_res}, glueContext))
```

With `MM/dd/yyyy HH:MM:SS` date formatting, it runs but returns null for the Date column. When I try any other date format besides this, it errors out. I suspect the date formatting may be the issue, but I am not certain.

Answer (score 0):

After converting string to timestamp you need to cast it to date type, like this:

`df = df.withColumn(df_col, df[df_col].cast("date"))`

Comment: Thank you so much but this still resulted in nulls. We ended up truncating the `HH:MM:SS` and it worked! I think this must be a data issue on our end.

Answer (score 0):

We ended up removing the `HH:MM:SS` portion of the date format and this worked for our needs. I would still be interested if anyone can figure out how to get the hours, minutes, seconds, and AM/PM to work, but we can do without for now.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where I was not able to convert the string `01/31/2023` to date with [`to_date`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.to_date.html) function at AWS Glue job, custom transform block.

Enabling the legacy mode of `timeParserPolicy` was the correct solution for my case.

```
spark.conf.set('spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy', 'LEGACY')
```

You can undo it (if necessary) using the corrected mode:

```
spark.conf.set('spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy', 'CORRECTED')
```

I made [this demo](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1SbqnTsRKYBB9BJ-hWob1JEb7PwPmwaNW?usp=sharing) with the input from your question, it might be helpful.

Some references about this issue:

- https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html
- [Parse date with slashes in Pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73394146/parse-date-with-slashes-in-pyspark/73395182#73395182)
- https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-migration-guide.html#query-engine (find `timeParserPolicy` if you in a rush)

Comment: Try those : 

    dataFrame.withColumn("OpenDate_aux",to_timestamp("OpenDate", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss z").cast(TimestampType())) ;   ... or ... 

    result_df.withColumn(\"date_aux\", to_date(result_df[\"abcd\"], \"dd.MM.yyyy\").cast(DateType()))\n"